# Sencha Ext 5 Grid -grid.reconfigure(store, cols) -locking/freezin grid column menu

Tags: extjs, extjs5

When I tried to reconfigure the grid with columns and stores, It is locking/freezing grid column level menu

```
grid.reconfigure(store, cols);
```

please provide your suggestion to address this issue.

Comment: You should add additional information, including some of the source you are using outside the one function call.  Also, information about what you were expecting to happen vs. what is actually happening will help to get you an answer.

Comment: It's impossible to suggest anything. Your question is missing too much information.

Answer (score 0):

Below script worked for me :

```
Ext.define('Overrides.grid.filters.Filters', {
    override: 'Ext.grid.filters.Filters',

    onReconfigure: function(grid, store, columns, oldStore) {
        var me = this;

        me.sep = Ext.destroy(me.sep);
        if (me.menuItems && me.menuItems[grid.id]) {
            me.menuItems[grid.id].destroy();
        }

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```